# Как убрать расстояние между виджетами в QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qlayout, qhboxlayout

Горизонтальный контейнер `box1` содержит в себе контейнеры `box2` и `box3`. 
`box2` - содержит в себе кнопки с изображениями, а 
`box3` - имеет цвет, поэтому его границы хорошо видны.

Мне нужно, чтобы между элементами контейнера `box2` и границей `box3` не было расстояния, т.е. чтобы они вплотную прижимались друг к другу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот картинка, которая находится на кнопках (picture.png). Такой узор нарисовал, чтобы было проще контролировать ситуацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как мне убрать расстояние между элементами контейнера `box2` и границей `box3`?

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(200, 300)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self) # Главный контейнер
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Main Box')
        main_box.addWidget(btn)

        box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(spacing = 0) # Контейнер для box2 и box3
        main_box.addLayout(box1)

        box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout() # Контенер для кнопок с изображениями

        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Color Box', alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        box1.addWidget(container)
        box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container) # Цветной контейнер

        box1.addLayout(box2)

        box3.addWidget(label)
        box3.addWidget(btn3)

        for i in range(0, 3):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
            btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('picture.png'))
            btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))
            btn.setStyleSheet(qss)
            box2.addWidget(btn)
        box2.addStretch(1)


qss = '''QPushButton {
             border: none;
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px;
         }'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте установить

```
btn.setFixedSize(60, 60)
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.resize(200, 300)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self) # Главный контейнер
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Main Box')
        main_box.addWidget(btn)

        box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(spacing = 0) # Контейнер для box2 и box3
        main_box.addLayout(box1)

        box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout() # Контенер для кнопок с изображениями

        btn3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Color Box', alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        box1.addWidget(container)
        box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container) # Цветной контейнер

        box1.addLayout(box2)

        box3.addWidget(label)
        box3.addWidget(btn3)

        for i in range(0, 3):
            btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
            btn.setFixedSize(60, 60)                              # <---
            btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('picture.png'))
            btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))
            btn.setStyleSheet(qss)
            box2.addWidget(btn)
        box2.addStretch(1)


qss = '''QPushButton {
             border: none;
             margin: 0px;
             padding: 0px;
             background-color: blue;
         }'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]